# Limit points via different paths

Tags: real-analysis, limits

We are given a positive function $f(x,y)$ on the domain $\mathbb{N} \times [0,1]$. We know all the limits $g(y) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n,y)$ for $y\in[0,1]$. $g(y)$ is finite for every $y \in [0,1]$.

Now, consider any sequence $\{y_k\}_{k\geq 1}$ such that $0 \leq y_k \leq 1 \forall k$. What can we say about $$\liminf_{n \to \infty} f(n,y_n)$$
Can we say $$\liminf_{n \to \infty} f(n,y_n) \in [\min g(y),\max g(y)]$$

My approach: I can prove this if I assume 'uniform convergence' of $f(n,y)$ over the index variable $y$.

For any $y \in [0,1]$, for any $\epsilon > 0 $, there exists $N(\epsilon,y)$ such that $\forall n \geq N(\epsilon,y)$, $|f(n,y) -g(y)| \leq \epsilon$. Define $N(\epsilon) = \max_y N(\epsilon,y)$ then for any $n \geq N(\epsilon)$ and any $\{y_n\}$, $|f(n,y_n) - g(y_n)| \leq \epsilon$. Therefore, $\liminf_{n \to \infty} f(n,y_n) \in [\min g -\epsilon,\max g + \epsilon] $.

However, in the above proof, I have assumed $N(\epsilon)$ is finite. I don't know if this can be assumed. Is there any other way to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Let $f(n,x)=n$ for $0 <x<\frac 1 n$ and $0$ for $x=0$ and for $x \geq \frac 1 n$. Then $f(n,y) \to 0$ for all $y$. If you take $f_n=\frac 1 {2n}$ the $f(n,y_n)=n$ so $\lim \inf f(n,y_n)=\infty$.

Actually we can even make the functions smooth . A standard construction  using bump functions shows that there exists functions $f(n,y)$ such that  $f(x)= \begin{array} {c} 1 \, \,\text {if} \,\,\frac1 {3n} <x<\frac 1 n \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \\0 \,\,  \text{if} \, \,x \in [0,\frac 1 {4n}] \cup [\frac 2 n, 1]  \end{array}$ with $0 \leq f(n,y) \leq 1$ for all $n$ and $y$.

Comment: For your example, $f(n,y)$ (or $f(n,x)$ in your notation) does not go to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ for $y=0$

Comment: @BlackJack21 I have edited.

Comment: would it be true if I impose $f(n,y)$ is continuous over the $y$ variable (or maybe even differentiable) for all $n$?

Comment: You can even construct an example where $f(n,y)$ is infintely differentiable in the variable $y$! @BlackJack21

Comment: It would be great if you can add such an example to the answer. I can image a nice smooth $f(n,y)$ by letting $f(n,y)$ decrease in $n$ slowly after $n \geq 1/y$  (instead of directly $0$ in your example). However, $f(n,0) = 0$ makes the function $f(n,y)$ discontinuous in $y$.

Comment: Also, does it help if I give you that $f(.,.)$ is bounded by $K$ for all $n,y$?

Comment: I have edited my answer. For your last question we can replace $f(n,x)=n$ by $f(n,x)=1$ in my example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123572/discussion-between-black-jack-21-and-kavi-rama-murthy).

Comment: Sorry to bother to you again. Can we say it is true if $f(n,y)$ is monotonically decreasing along $n$ for each value of $y$? No need to give an example. Also, if not, can you describe a condition that does make the statement true

Comment: @BlackJack21 If $f(n,y)$ is decreasing in $n$ and continuous in $y$ and if $g(y)$ is also continuous then $f_n \to g$ uniformly. The conclusion holds whenever $f_n \to g$ uniformly.